# No PropertyType exists with the supplied alias: umbracoWidth

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to create a Media programmatically in Umbraco 7.4.1 but when I try to use MediaType.File I'm getting the error

> No PropertyType exists with the supplied alias: umbracoWidth

But when I change it to MediaType.Image its' saving and working properly. When I try to view the CMS it is indeed the mediaType File doesn't have a property of width. So I'm not sure why upon executing the `media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);` it's trying to look for a property of `umbracoWidth` even though I was using `MediaType.File`

Below is how I define my code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File);
        media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);
        Services.MediaService.Save(media);
    }
}
```

But if I change the code from `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File` to `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image` it's working correctly but the problem is the media type is not correct. Specially if i'm uploading a video or PDF file. Though it was successfully able to create a new media but the type will be wrong since it's specified as Image. I want to know how to solve the issue when using mediatype File

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch manually the media type when uploading.

Eg. check on the file extension if it is gif/jpeg/jpg, the change to `Image`, otherwise use `File`.

Internally in Umbraco they use this code to know if the file is an image (or not):

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the file extension corresponds to an image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="extension">The file extension.</param>
    /// <returns>A value indicating whether the file extension corresponds to an image.</returns>
    public bool IsImageFile(string extension)
    {
        if (extension == null) return false;
        extension = extension.TrimStart('.');
        return UmbracoConfig.For.UmbracoSettings().Content.ImageFileTypes.InvariantContains(extension);
    }
```

This is the [source from the snippet](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/086157cff8fc7d34596244265a19caa847c6936b/src/Umbraco.Core/IO/MediaFileSystem.cs#L346) above